# Crash when calling removeItemAtPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I will call save(archive) and remove method on main thread. And unarchived local fails after remove one. However, I can't reappear the crash myself.But it appear most users.
Crash log like that:

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x0000000170043780
-[XYPHPostModel(Manager) removeDraft:]

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  (Missing)                      0x170043780 (Missing)
1  (Missing)                      0x170043780 (Missing)
2  Foundation                     0x18545555c -[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:] + 84
3  discover                       0x10023fe2c -[XYPHPostModel(Manager) removeDraft:] (XYPHPostModel+Manager.m:130)
4  discover                       0x10023f4fc -[XYPHPostModel(Manager) finishPost] (XYPHPostModel+Manager.m:40)
5  discover                       0x100252024 -[XYPHPostNoteModel(Manager) setPostStatusToSuccess:] (XYPHPostNoteModel+Manager.m:600)
6  discover                       0x10025275c __43-[XYPHPostNoteModel(Manager) postToServer:]_block_invoke_2 (XYPHPostNoteModel+Manager.m:639)
7  discover                       0x10082ec3c __89-[XYAPIClient xy_requestPutWithRoute:withParams:withKeyPath:withPattern:success:failure:]_block_invoke (XYAPIClient.m:767)
8  discover                       0x100ef2428 -[XYRKHTTPSessionManager handleResponse:success:failure:] (XYRKHTTPSessionManager.m:454)
9  discover                       0x100ef0774 __78-[XYRKHTTPSessionManager putForRouteNamed:pattern:parameters:success:failure:]_block_invoke (XYRKHTTPSessionManager.m:254)
10 discover                       0x1007a5c2c __116-[AFHTTPSessionManager dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:URLString:parameters:uploadProgress:downloadProgress:success:failure:]_block_invoke.80 (AFHTTPSessionManager.m:290)
11 discover                       0x1007b8ba0 __72-[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke_2.150 (AFURLSessionManager.m:308)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x18388a1fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x18388a1bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18388eb2c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 428
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1849ae810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1849ac3fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1848da2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
18 GraphicsServices               0x18638e198 GSEventRunModal + 180
19 UIKit                          0x18a9217fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
20 UIKit                          0x18a91c534 UIApplicationMain + 208
21 discover                       0x1006bf610 main (main.m:31)
22 (Missing)                      0x1838bd5b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: I'am sorry, but this provides absolutely no context (which is critical if you want to resolve a crash) and thus is hardly answerable. You should take a look at [ask] and take the [StackOverflow's Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) in order to understand how the site works.

Comment: can you share some code please?

Comment: Please give us some context or code involved in the crash.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you try delete a file, but you haven't permission over your specific folder.

[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:] + 84

We need more context, for we try to help you.

Comment: I would only call the NSFilemanager methods on main thread.  But I will unarchived the saved files after removed one.  It seems like that:  [NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]; [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:];

Comment: Permission error will not cause crash.  Filemanager works fine from multiple threads, as long as you follow the rules (and OP's crash is on the main thread).